# Advanced thinking on Caesar Cipher program in C

Tags: c, encryption

```
#include <stdio.h>

void caesar (char cipher[], int shift);

int main ()
{

char cipher[200];
int shift;

printf("Enter text to be encrypted (in small letter): ");
gets(cipher);

printf("Number of shift to right? : ");
scanf("%d", &shift);

caesar (cipher, shift);

return 0;
}

void caesar (char cipher[], int shift)
{
int i = 0;

while (cipher[i] != '\0')
{
    if ((cipher[i] + shift) >= 97 && (cipher[i] + shift) <= 122)
    {
        cipher[i] += (shift);
    }
    else
    {
        cipher[i] += (shift - 25);
    }
    i++;
}
printf("%s", cipher);
}
```

How can I ignore the operation of spaces? I mean, I want to add spaces in my converted/decrypted string. While I running this program it vanishes the spaces from the encrypted string. How can I do this? Suppose that, "this is a pen" is would become: "uijt jt b qfo" if right shift by 1.

Comment: You can ignore spaces by adding an `if` at the top of the `while` loop, e.g. `if ( cipher[i] != ' ' ) {  ...  }`  The ... part is the `if/else` statement that you already have.

Comment: It this for [aizu online](http://judge.u-aizu.ac.jp/onlinejudge/description.jsp?id=0017)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check whether a character is a letter before shifting. Your code shifts everything and checks only whether a character is a valid letter afterwards to detect wrapping. (It also doesn't make the puctuation and spaces vanish, it converts them to non-printable characters with ASCII values below 32.)

You could also enforce correct wrapping by using the modulo operator:

```
void caesar(char cipher[], int shift)
{
    char *p = cipher;

    while (*p)
    {
        if ('a' <= *p && *p <= 'z') {
            *p = 'a' + (*p - 'a' + shift) % 26;
        }
        p++;
    }
}
```

If you want to auto-detect the shift, just use brute force for all 26 possible shifts and check for common expected substrings:

```
int autocaesar(char cipher[])
{
    int shift = 0;

    while (shift < 26) {
        if (strstr(cipher, "the")) return shift;
        if (strstr(cipher, "this")) return shift;
        if (strstr(cipher, "that")) return shift;

        caesar(cipher, 1);
        shift++;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

The function `strstr` is in `<string.h>` and finds a substring in an string. This is done very crudely here: It is not enforced that `"the"` is a word of its own. Also, the check is case sensitive.

Note that the cipher is shifted by one character at a time, because the original string will be shifted continuously. If nothing os found, it will have wrapped over to contain the original string.

Comment: @chux: The condition `if ('a' <= c && c <= 'z')` is true if `c` is a lower-case Latin letter in ASCII.

Comment: Ah yes, had it turned around.

Comment: @chux: I (sometimes) prefer the symmetry of the `<=` operators to the overall symmetry of the expression (if that makes sense). I agree that can be hard to read at first sight.

Comment: 6.01 or half a dozen of the other.  It makes a smaller difference, but either is acceptable.